# Chaining spring view resolvers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there an alternative way to achieve the next behavior in spring?:

Given path xxx/yyy

1) Look up for static/html/xxx/yyy.html

2) In case html doesn't exist look up for WEB-INF/xxx/yyy.jsp

I was trying the next config. But it seems UrlBasedViewResolver fails and doesn't delegate to the next ViewResolver.

So it seems u can't actually chain two UrlBasedViewResolver in Spring, am I right?

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>          

<bean id="htmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/static/html/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, you can't, because UrlBasedViewResolver (or InternalResourceViewResolver) always resolves the view and is not possible to delegate to next ViewResolver. Reference says that this kind of ViewResolver [always need to be the last](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html).

There are some workarounds that may help you, as [implementing your custom ViewResolver](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/03/01/chaining-multiple-view-resolvers-in-spring-using-two-internalresourceviewresolver/).